# Handle user on facebook like gate

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, facebook-apps, facebook-page

I'm coding a facebook like gate and this is a screenshot of my config : http://www.kreatoo.com/rav/facebook_info.png

I need the Signed Request ($facebook->getSignedRequest()) for know if the user like this page or not, and i have this information only the first time. If i click on a link i loose this information..

In second time, when i login my user (with $facebook->getLoginUrl()), facebook redirect on the server (www.vibrantmarketing.ca/...) and not on apps (https://www.facebook.com/coppertone/app_432377713445313..).. I try with "redirect_uri" or "next" option but nothing...

Thank you all for help

PS : For interested the application is : https://www.facebook.com/pages/TestCactOos/255835411190164?sk=app_335457189856398

Answer (score 0):

Let's start in your first quesiton

- Facebook Like Gating - you actually don't need to request to sign in your app just to gate your Facebook Like. In your situation for example, you use the app for Facebook page and you can get the SignedRequest on that moment buy not requiring the user to sign to your app.
- Again , I check out your app and it redirects me in the url below: which is good for me, the only thing you need to do is redirect your user if the page was not viewed in the iFrame.

  - https://www.vibrantmarketing.ca/coppertone/facebook/littlemiss/en/like#_=_

Note:
One thing, when I checked your app it redirects time to time. I think it's because of your Javascript at the bottom of your page which logins everytime.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, and sorry for my english. I try to redirect but i can't know if i'm on an iFrame or directly on browzer (with $_SERVER) ? The button is for login the user, for pictures, ...